# Concatenate X number of rows in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have tibbles with different numbers of rows and columns; and would like to concatenate each row to one long row (preferably using tidyverse). Please see example data below.

```
#Example data 1:

x <- as_tibble(matrix(1:9, ncol=3))

#wanted:
  x = c(1,4, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9)


#Example data 2: 
x <- as_tibble(matrix(1:10, ncol=2))

#wanted:
  x = c(1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 10)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can transpose and concatenate

```
c(t(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @akrun is the simplest one, I think. Here is a more complicated workaround :P

```
> unlist(split(x,1:nrow(x)),use.names = FALSE)
[1] 1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9
```